# Set div size of its background image

Tags: html, css

Is it possible with CSS/HTML to resize some box to match exactly it's background image size? Without using javascript.

For instance let's say I have a simplest div:

```
<div class="image">TEST</div>

.image {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

And I would like to resize it to those 350x150 dimensions without hardcoding those values. Also I cannot put any content inside this div.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Dane/

**EDIT**: I see a lot of answers I already was aware of, thank you for them, but that's not the solution here unfortunately. Below I'm explaining why I need such functionality.

What I'm trying to do is a form with steps (buttons previous and next). In session I hold all the values the user has input but there are some buttons which will add more functionality for the user (like multiple dynamically added rows for data). I'm doing it with jQuery of course, but I want the form to be able to work when there is no java script enabled.

Now to the point - I was trying to find out how to tell the difference which button the user has clicked. The case is all my submit buttons need to be images and the simplest solution `<input type="image"/>` doesn't send info about the button clicked with `POST` data. That's why I came to this solution:

```
<input class="submit_img" type="submit" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/108x23); width:108px; height: 23px;" value=" " name="some" />

/* Submit button with image */
input.submit_img {
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0 1px 1px;
    border: solid 0px #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XRvqV/

This way my form will submit all the data **AND** I will know which button the user clicked. Also the button looks fine, like it should look. I was wondering though if it was possible to make it a little more portable - my buttons all have different widths for different functions. Can someone suggest another approach here?

Comment: you can't do this with pure css/html. You need javascript to look at the image, get its dimensions, and set those into the css.

Comment: you can change background image size same as div

Comment: Struggling to think of a use-case why it would be necessary to do this in the first place.

Comment: Ok I think I will include some more info why am I trying to do this that way, edit incoming soon.

Comment: I've edited my question, please let me know if someone knows how to do what I need. Thanks

Comment: @KeluThatsall I didn't understand what are you asking. The first question has nothing to do with your edit, and it's unclear what was your question after the edit.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. CSS is not aware of the the image size. You can do it easily with JQuery.

[JQuery exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/5Dane/25/)

```
$(function(){
    var bg = $("div.image").css('background-image');
    bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = bg;
    $("div.image").css("width",newImg.width);
    $("div.image").css("height",newImg.height);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack and doesn't use `background-image` (uses an `img` tag instead), but is the only way I can think of without using JS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.pandafix.com/pandafix/images/untitled_1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        some text
        <br/>
        some more text
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        text text text
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
}
```

Basically, you allow an `img` tag to determine the height and width of a container. Then, overlay whatever content you want on top of the image (I'm assuming you want to put something on top).

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fDNE/)**

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you a alternative way to solve your problem. if you use bootstrap you can involve a div to make resizable image.

```
<div class="img-responsive">
     <img src="test.jpg" width='xxx' height='yyy' alt='test'>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using just HTML. But you can do this using HTML!

You should try this:

```
background-size: values;
```

This way, you will resize the background-image to the size of the container!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly.

The only solution it would be fetching the BG of the DIV element and attach new DOM img element to the DOM node, afterwards you could use the info of the image to add the proper with and height..

if you are willing to use jquery you can do this.

```
      $(function(){
        $('.image').each(function(index,element){
          var _t = $(this);
          _t.data("LinkedImg","LinkedImage"+index);
          $('body').append(
          $('<img />',{
           id:"LinkedImage"+index,
           src:_t.css('background-image')
          }).hide());
        });

        $('document').on('load',function(){
        $('.image').each(function(index,element){
          var _t = $(this);
          var _tmp_img = $('#'+ _t.data("LinkedImg"));
          _t.css({
                width:_tmp_img.width(),
                height: _tmp_img.height()
          });
        });
        });
})
```